# Working completely offline in typesafe activator

Tags: java, playframework, typesafe-activator

I have downloaded typesafe activator full version to start working with Play framework. After creating play-java project when I run `activator run` command it starts downloading lots of libraries which are already present in `~/activator-1.3.2/repository` local folder.

May be it is updating them but I want to work completely offline due to my slow net connection. I have tried `activator -Dactivator.checkForUpdates=false run` but it still downloads them.

Comment: any solution to this? It looks like activator uses the internet for accessing resources from amazon S3, as well as downloading dependencies...

Comment: @RichAshworth I didn't find the solution which I wanted, for the first time it(Play 2.3 and up) has to connect to internet to download all dependency but after that it runs without downloading anything unless there is an update. Also Play 2.2 (offline setup) doesn't includes activator and works without downloading anything.

Answer (score -2):

Just add `offline := true` into your app's **build.sbt**.

Comment: It is still downloading all those jar libraries.

Comment: activator can be used outside of an applicaiton directory for creating a project structure etc. In these instances, there is no build.sbt (that I am aware of)